# Degree symbol in grails

Tags: json, grails, utf-8, http-get

Hi I'm doing this get request to get a JSON which contain a degree symbol.

```
 def get(url){
        url = new URL(url)
        def connection = url.openConnection()
        connection.setRequestMethod("GET")
        connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json;charset=utf-8");


        connection.doOutput = true
        connection.connect()

        print resp
        resp

    }
```

But my symbol becomes units":"�C " when view on browser, and **ï¿½** in console. How do I solve?

Answer (score 0):

Try processing the json data form the url using JsonSlulrper as follows:

```
def resp = new JsonSlurper().parseText(url.text)
```

Also in your HTML views/layouts, make sure you apply encoding:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    ........
```